# pre_save signal using tastypie api not allowing me to access "instance" field

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm working on this small Django project in which I'm using `pre_save` signals to update a table in which I save the cumulative value of a certain quantity, whenever a new Transaction is created or modified, the corresponding value in the table is updated. If I add a transaction manually from the admin page everything works fine but today I tried to create a new Transaction through a POST request using `tastypie` generated api, the problem is that when my `update_total_if_changed` function is called by the signal, the `instance` parameter is `/api/v1/transaction/` instead of the actual python object, therefore I get "Transaction has no FieldName." since the `instance` actually points to the tastypie entrypoint instead of the newly created object.

Below you can see the code of my signal

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Transaction)
def update_total_if_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        obj = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    except sender.DoesNotExist: #new transaction
        tw, new = TotalWaste.objects.get_or_create(depot=instance.depot, waste = instance.waste)
        tw.total += instance.quantity
        tw.save()
    else:
        if not obj.quantity == instance.quantity: # Field has changed
        tw, new = TotalWaste.objects.get_or_create(depot=instance.depot, waste = instance.waste)
            tw.total = tw.total + instance.quantity - obj.quantity 
            tw.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, I forgot to define the specific Resource, therefore the endpoint was not seen as a set of objects but just as a link that didn't point to anything, therefore I could not access the needed field.